# How to provide correct settings for gradle?

Tags: gradle, credentials, artifactory

Using Jenkins for CI, I need to use hidden credentials for `Gradle` or `maven` publishing. My credentials are applied in Jenkins rather than in source code. Maven settings are in a `settings.xml`, but I would like to define properties in Jenkins. What would I use in a command-line to do this? I imagine

```
gradle -Dsomething.username=blah -Dsomething.password=secret
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way but this is how we do it: we define target maven repository in `build.gradle` using custom project properties and then provide those properties via command line:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "https://your-repo-server.company.com/your-built-artifacts") {
                authentication(userName: project.getProperties()['nexusUploadUsername'], password: project.getProperties()['nexusUploadPassword'])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`gradle -PnexusUploadUsername=blah -PnexusUploadPassword=secret`

You can also take one step further and configure them as Jenkins build parameters or environment variables in order to prevent people from seeing them in logs (do not forget to set that 'Mask passwords' checkbox): `gradle -PnexusUploadUsername=$JENKINS_NEXUS_USER -PnexusUploadPassword=$JENKINS_NEXUS_PASSWORD`.